# autocomplete android

Tags: android

How i can get absolute position of  my object selected by autocomplete. When i use arg2 retrieve a relative position in autocomplete drop down list. I want a position of selected object on my original list.

My code:

```
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_friends);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, friendsListNameOrder);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

        textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            friendsListNameOrder.get(arg2);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not as elegant as you would hope:

```
    final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium", "France", "Italy",
            "Germany", "Spain" };

    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.AutoCompleteTextView01);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.log_item, COUNTRIES);

    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            String s = ((TextView) arg1).getText().toString();
            Log.e("Test", s + " position: "
                    + getArrayIndex(COUNTRIES, s));
        }
    });
```

where getArrayIndex is:

```
public final int getArrayIndex(String[] myArray, String myObject) {
    int ArraySize = Array.getLength(myArray);// get the size of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].equals(myObject)) {
            return (i);
        }
    }
    return (-1);// didn't find what I was looking for
}
```

Comment: Ok....if i have two equals country...example : COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain" ,"Spain"};

Comment: it will return the first instance of the list.  Note that you really aren't looking at the list, but rather a cursor to the list: that is why i take the selected value and bring it back to search the originating array for it.  If you need to uniquely identify two matching rows, this autocomplete is probably not your best choice.  Or you will need to have an adapter that links to an object that has an identity column.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter and override the getPosition() method. In the method code, you get the position from the original data list.

```
@Override
public int getPosition(Object item) {
    return friendsListNameOrder.indexOf(item);
}
```

Although I imagine this might cause some complications, it might be beneficial when you start adding more features.